# C++ OpenSource project for beginner programmer?

Tags: c++, open-source

I`m a beginner C++ programmer. And I want to pursue my career in system- and driver-programming.
Can you suggest me an opensource projects to I improve my skills in low-level development?

I am looking for a project with the following characteristic:
- on C\C++ language based 
- a small project with a small amount of code, yet 
- UNIX-based systems designed

Do you know that something like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575511/what-c-open-source-projects-have-good-and-clean-code-to-learn-from
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534311/examples-of-modern-c-in-action

Comment: Maybe you should look for a mentor instead...not sure opensource projects want "beginners"...just a thought

Comment: Open source projects are always looking for beginners unless they're run by clueless leaders.  There are plenty of contributions to be made to a project, even if they don't start with coding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the google summer of code projects page! These are all open source, and many of them are based on C/C++. Each project lists ideas that are aimed at outsiders / beginners.

Here is last year's page: http://code.google.com/soc/2008/ Google has not yet decided on which projects are participating this year, but this information will become available within the next couple of weeks (before the end of march 2009) along with a fresh list of ideas.

If you're a student in a College/University you can get lucky and even get mentoring through the GSOC project. But even if not, they will really value any contribution you can make.

Answer (score 2):

Always work on open source projects that you actually use and care about.  If you don't use the project yourself, why should you do good work on it?

Answer (score 1):

What about Minix 3? It's a great way to learn about low level programming.

Answer (score 1):

Start your own open source project.

Host it on Google Code

Make something does something great or makes something else easier to use

Use it and iterate it

Answer (score 1):

Along the same lines as Sourceforge Help Wanted, there's a website called OpenHatch.org that lists bugs from open source projects that need attention as well as potential mentors. In particular, you can browse for [bitesized](https://openhatch.org/search/?q=&toughness=bitesize&language=C%2B%2B) bugs that might be a good place for a beginner to start.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [sourceforge's help wanted](http://sourceforge.net/people/)?

Edit: And as a personal suggestion, I'm not sure it fits your requirements, but the [transmission bittorrent](http://trac.transmissionbt.com/ticket/7) client needs an implementation of Kademlia DHT in C, which is pretty low level networking.